# Compressed beautiful font for the headers

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I am currently writing my dissertation. I am looking for a compressed font like the picture below for my headers. What is the nearest font to this, preferably open type? I am using `xelatex` and `memoir` for my thesis, So I can easily change fonts.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the methods suggested in [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/15925) ?

Comment: For your headers or for your headings?

Comment: WhatTheFont shows that this seems to be a Univers Ultra Cond Thin font: http://tinyurl.com/982w2xw

Comment: @AndrewSwann, those methods are for when you have the original PDF that I don't have.

Comment: @ℝaphink, For the headings like section and title headings. Your url is not working but I found the font:http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/univers/ultra-cond-thin/ Unfortunately it is not free, Is there any free alternative that matches as much as possible?

Comment: @rowman: It's hard to find good alternatives for condensed fonts. One that is quite similar is [Steelfish](http://www.dafont.com/steelfish.font).

Comment: No, What-the-font allows you to upload an image for font recognition.

Comment: @ℝaphink: Could you post an answer to the canonical question, showing how to use WhatTheFont / how it works? So far, it's only been mentioned in a meager comment there.

Comment: @percusse: Well the question was not really about how to identify the font. Using WhatTheFont is very straightforward, all you need to do is upload the picture and help the program recognize the letters, and it will suggest matching fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This font seems to be a [Univers Ultra Condensed Thin](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/univers/ultra-cond-thin/):

[image: Univers Ultra Cond Thin]

A free (as in free beer) replacement might be [Steelfish Rg](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/steelfish):

[image: Steelfish Rg]

Steelfish Rg is a bit bolder than Univers Ultra Cond Thin. There are Steelfish Light and Steelfish Ultralight faces, too, but they are not free. Example with Steelfish Light:

[image: Steelfish Light]